# Laravel throwing QueryException after update MySQL to 8.0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

After upgrading MySQL to version 8.0, Any attempt to migrate database throws exception indicating `unknown authenticaion method`

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown t  
  o the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_sche  
  ma = wiki and table_name = migrations)                                       



  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown t  
  o the client                                                                 



  [PDOException]                                                               
  PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to t  
  he client [caching_sha2_password]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that MySQL 8.0.4 has changed its default authentication mechanism to `caching_sha2_password`. ([second clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-4.html#mysqld-8-0-4-security))

In order to make it authenticate with your `.env` `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` follow this instructions:

- Add `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` to your `my.cnf`

  On CentOS/RHEL it's located on `/etc/my.cnf`.
  On Debian/Ubuntu, I do believe it's located on `/etc/mysql` .
  This will revert back the default authentication mechanism back to username password.

Login to your mysql and follow procedure

- Remove existing database user and recreate it.

  In order to remove the user:
  `DROP USER yourUser@localhost;` (with assumption your db is local)
- Create another user
  `CREATE USER user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`
  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbName.* TO user@localhost;`
- Flush privileges
  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Logout of mysql and run:

On Centos/RHEL: `systemctl restart mysqld`
On Debian/Ubuntu: `systemctl restart mysql.service`

I could get it up and running without database removal.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-4.html#mysqld-8-0-4-security
- https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/
- https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392

Answer (score 0):

on windows; terminate sqld from task manager, now from XAMPP control panel stop and restart MySQL.